# SQL query which give me result with same and IN column

Tags: php, sql

I have this table:

[image]

and I am trying to get id_combination where id_attribute_value is in 19 and 21 and 24 result should be 25 but I don't know how to build query.

Can you someone help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried to build the query? This is not a free programming solutions' site.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id_combination
FROM table_name 
WHERE id_attribute_value IN (19,21,24) 
GROUP BY id_combination 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_attribute_value) = 3
```

Just replace `table_name` for your table name.

Comment: This give me result:13,16,16,19,22,25,25,25 and I want only 25 because I want result which has id_attribute_value 19 and 21 and 24.

Comment: @folpy Just want to add one more point here, if you want distinct rows then use `DISTINCT` keyword with your `SELECT` query, like this: `SELECT DISTINCT id_combination ...`

Comment: When I add DISTINCT I get same result as I wrote above.

Comment: So what you want is an `id_combination` where it meets all the numbers?

Comment: As I wrote above result should be 25 because is it id_combination with all id_attribute_value.

Comment: I mean with id_attribute_value 19,21 and 24

Comment: Is in 19, 21, 24 means 19, 21 or 24

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong info it should be in 19 and 21 and 24 do you understand how I mean it?

Comment: Totally got what you said now

Comment: You should also edit your question so it will not make other people confused.

Comment: I edit my question. I am going to make some workaround with PHP I thought that I could do this via one sql query.

Comment: It seems that the updated answer is what you want, isn't it?